# Understanding basicity of heterocyclic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I want to know the reason why,

Pyrrolidine

[image]

is more basic than,

Piperidine

[image]

Mainly I want  to know what affect  does  the ring structure have on basicity  and how does 5 membered rings and 6 membered  rings containing a electron rich atom,  affect the basicity?